# Не запускается MySQL 8.2 Command Line Client

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Я некоторое время назад установил MySQL 8.2. Ярлык **MySQL 8.2 Command Line Client** должна запустить командную строку с просьбой ввести пароль для входа, но при попытке открыть его командная строка открывается и мгновенно закрывается.

[image: Ярлык MySQL 8.2 Command Line Client]

В качестве альтернативы я сейчас захожу в *MySQL Server 8.2/bin* и там выполняю команду `mysql -u root -p`, чтобы использовать MySQL в командной строке.

Может нужно как-то переписать строку *Объект*, чтобы иным образом запустить MySQL?

Сообщения в терминале:

```
mysql: [ERROR] Failed to open required defaults file: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.2\my.ini
mysql: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

Comment: Открываешь окно CMD. Тащишь на него ярлык. Жмёшь Enter. Читаешь сообщения.

Comment: @Akina ```mysql: [ERROR] Failed to open required defaults file: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.2\my.ini
mysql: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!```

Comment: Ну осталось найти правильное местоположение файла настроек и указать его в строке запуска в свойствах ярлыка...

Comment: @Akina её там нет. Где она может быть? Я ничего не удалял дополнительно, не настраивал ничего после установки.

Comment: Ну если БЕЗ указания CLI стартует - то в свойствах ярлыка тупо удали указание на местоположение файла, что за проблемы-то? Ну или читать https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/option-files.html и искать...